# Different gemspec code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemspecs

I have a local and production rails app running. Having problems, so I did a diff and found amoung many things, but the most curious was that the gemspec was different! For the same gemspec: **action-mailer-3.0.13.gemspec** I have different code!

My local one has:

```
s.name = "actionmailer"
s.version = "3.0.13"
s.description = "Email on Rails. Compose, deliver, ....
s.email = "david@loudthinking.com"
s.homepage = "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
```

and the exact same from production has:

```
s.name = %q{actionmailer}
s.version = "3.0.13"
s.description = %q{Email on Rails. Compose, deliver ...
s.email = %q{david@loudthinking.com}
s.files = ["CHANGELOG", "README.rdoc", "MIT-LICENSE", "lib/action_m...
s.homepage = %q{http://www.rubyonrails.org}
```

So am wondering what is going on here? Any ideas?

Edit: Also

```
Mine: s.rubygems_version = "1.8.24"
Prd:  s.rubygems_version = %q{1.5.1}
```

I think there is the clue in this, Maybe time to read up on this gemspec thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem. Both scripts are actually same, apart from the s.files part in the second. %{some_string} is just another way how you can make a string in ruby...